# Reabertura de pergunta duplicata mesmo ela continuando sendo duplicata

Tags: debate, fechamento

Recentemente fechei a pergunta abaixo como duplicata de uma que eu já havia feito, pois a solução dela servia perfeitamente pra dúvida apresentada.

Esta é a duplicada:

[Como filtrar Coluna no JTable com dados do tipo Calendar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258061/como-filtrar-coluna-no-jtable-com-dados-do-tipo-calendar)

Essa é a pergunta que possui resposta pra ela:

[RowFilter.regexFilter não filtra colunas do tipo Date na JTable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122291/rowfilter-regexfilter-n%C3%A3o-filtra-colunas-do-tipo-date-na-jtable)

Como frequento a tag e como a pergunta mais antiga foi minha, entendo que a solução aí responde perfeitamente a dúvida, mas a mesma foi reaberta, mesmo continuando com um problema já respondido.

O que fazer nesse caso? As edições pós-fechamento mantiveram a dúvida que motivou o fechamento, ou seja, a pergunta continua sendo duplicata mas foi reaberta, e pelo que vi, por alguns usuários que não costumam responder na tag do tema.

Comment: Se a pessoa não consegue transpor o que está na resposta da pergunta original para o próprio contexto, às vezes é o caso de reabrir mesmo. E *talvez* seja o caso de fechar novamente depois de respondida. Prefiro não falar muito porque está fora da minha especialidade.

Answer (score 8):

Fechei ela como duplicata de novo.

Temos esses comentários do OP:

> Eu vi a sua solução é bem viavel, eu havia lido em algum lugar sobre o RowSorter solicitar o toString como voce mesmo debugou e notou isso a aquela classe foi muito bem elaborada, Parabens. – Denis Benjamim [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258061/como-filtrar-coluna-no-jtable-com-dados-do-tipo-calendar#comment529329_258061)

> Por que foi reaberta? – Denis Benjamim [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258061/como-filtrar-coluna-no-jtable-com-dados-do-tipo-calendar#comment529651_258061)

A julgar pelos comentários do OP, me parece que a pergunta que havia sido linkada como duplicata havia deixado ele satisfeito. Também entendo que não houve nenhum tipo de debate pela reabertura. Logo, não acho que deveria ter sido reaberta.

Comment: E você como um usuário que frequenta a tag e tem  bastante conhecimento sobre o tema, analisando o problema dele e a resposta linkada, não é uma solução? Digo, o problema dele em si é o mesmo que eu tive, **filtrar uma coluna de tipo datas com RowSorter**.

Comment: @Articuno Me parece sim que a resposta que eu dei à sua pergunta há muito tempo serve como resposta à pergunta dele. No entanto, isso não é algo óbvio de se ver neste caso (embora me pareça que o OP tenha conseguido ver).

Comment: @Articuno E a medalha de ouro na tag que nós dois temos dá o poder de fechar como duplicata com um único voto exatamente por isso: temos a experiência necessária para perceber detalhes que a maioria dos demais usuários não perceberia, e portanto temos muito mais capacidade de julgar o que é ou não duplicata mesmo em casos onde isso esteja bem longe de ser óbvio.

Comment: Exatamente, e eu nem presumi má intenção nos que reabriram não, eu já votei fechamento  equivocado algumas vezes, errar é algo que acontece mesmo,  só que  nesse caso assim que li eu tinha certeza de que era um problema que tive e trouxe pro site, no mínimo  eu queria entender o lado de quem reabriu. E essa capacidade tem me feito refletir melhor, por isso tenho tomado um cuidado a mais na hora de fechar.

Comment: @Articuno Entendo que se fosse esse o caso, de ter sido fechado como duplicata por engano, algum dos usuários que reabriu deveria pelo menos ter postado algum comentário na pergunta. Para defender fechamentos que podem ser controversos, vale comentar também, embora o link para essa pergunta aqui no meta já sirva para esse propósito.